# Display statistics like the number of answered questions per day

Tags: feature-request

We are trying to answer questions but doesn't see the result. The only thing we are seeing is the amount of questions there are.

Isn't it an idea to show also the solved questions per day?

Bring some positive feedback to the users!

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear what it is you're talking about. Can you please add some details here?

Comment: Haha Okey i will take this as a no :)

Comment: Take it as - we don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: You'll like a way to see how many questions were answered during a day? Does that only concerns the questions asked that day or all the questions? Something like `50% of the questions asked today were answered.` ??

Comment: I think... THINK he wants to know how many accepted answers he has in a single day.... I could be wrong though

Comment: I want to see some positive feedback instead of a enormous number that doesn't mean any thing anymore. I think it's for the user nicer to see what there is accomplished in a day.

Comment: @Julldar not what i did, what we all did together!

Comment: do you mean answers or accepted answers?

Comment: @erik Accepted answers, but i get it guys i should make my questions more clear!

Comment: "a enormous number that doesn't mean any thing anymore" - the number of questions only doesn't mean anything anymore because SO is overrun with a ton of crappy questions. A huge number of questions on SO should ideally be a very good thing if you think of every question as a potential reference solution to a hard problem. But with question quality as it is, showing the number of answered crap questions doesn't mean anything either.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is such a bad idea. Beta sites already show a few Site Stats in the sidebar.

[image: Beer Site Stats]

I'm not sure why this isn't displayed on larger sites, but it could be, as you say, because the numbers would be so large that they're meaningless. You can see some stats already on the main Stack Exchange site, if you go to the [All Sites tab](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest). % Answered is displayed there, so it's pretty easy to figure out how many answered questions we have overall.

I think better metrics for the sprawling huge sites in the network are found on the individual tag [Top User](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers) pages. There you can see a breakdown of how many questions were asked and what percentage were answered for a specific tag for the past 7 days, 30 days, and all time.